# Get rid of the single quotes in dates codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello i am facing a problemm using the query builder in CodeIgniter. The problem is that it wraps the date using single quotes. The query is shown like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `enquiries`
WHERE DAY(enquiry_date) = 'DAY(CURDATE())'
AND YEAR(enquiry_date) = 'YEAR(CURDATE())'
AND MONTH(enquiry_date) = 'MONTH(CURDATE())'
```

of course it will never return any results because of the single quotes. Is there any way i get rid of them? or do i have to do a hardcoded query?

If i execute the same query from phpmyadmin sql console like this

```
SELECT * FROM `enquiries` WHERE DAY(enquiry_date) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(enquiry_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(enquiry_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

it works fine.

My method:

```
public function enquiries_get(){
    $this->load->model('Model_enquiries');
    $enquiries = $this->Model_enquiries->get_many_by(array('DAY(enquiry_date)' => 'DAY(CURDATE())', 'YEAR(enquiry_date)' => 'YEAR(CURDATE())', 'MONTH(enquiry_date)' => 'MONTH(CURDATE())' ));
    if ($enquiries) {
        $this->response(array('status' => 'success', 'status_code' => '200', 'message' => '200 OK', 'response' => $enquiries));
    } else {
        $this->response(array('status' => 'failure', 'status_code' => '404', 'message' => '404 Not Found', 'response' => 'We couldn\'t find any enquiries for today. Please check again later.'), REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

 }
```

any ideas?

Comment: The `set()` function takes a third argument that can be used to leave the values as-is, something necessary for calling functions like this. The [query builder docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) explains this.

Answer (score 1):

you can try php function to get today's date ,year and month like this....

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$day = date('D');
```

And pass variables in your query directly...!!